# Different Avro Namespaces for classes generated in different applications

Tags: maven, avro, confluent-schema-registry, avro-tools

I'm trying to generate classes from the same Avro schema for Java application as a producer and C# application as a consumer. If I chose a namespace for the schema in Java style I can generate classes directly into a package like: `com.example.avro.generated` but the C# application have a different project structure and naming conventions. It would be weird to see such kind of namespace among folders like: `Components.Email.Notifications`. And vice versa. 
If I chose to have different namespaces the schema registry service will not validate my message because it will consider them to be different schemas.
I know that I can use GenericRecord and fill it's fields manually without classes generation but it's inconvenient.

Is there any way to generate classes having different namespaces?

Comment: I would worry more about if the data can actually be serialized appropriately rather than following naming conventions/working around class generation limitations. The namespace is defined by the record schema type itself, not decided by Java/.NET

Comment: But Avro being tech-agnostic, one should not worry about serialization/deserialization. In an ideal world, of course.

Worrying about conventions is a good thing, after all having a register for schemas is all about schema convention 